# Can't find symbole varible NSD_SERVICE

Tags: java, android, nsd

I'm trying to run the following piece of code:

```
 mNsdManager = (NsdManager) context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NSD_SERVICE);
```

but when building it complains that "cannot find symbol variable NSD_SERVICE"

Tried to make a clean build, invalidate caches and restart.

Any help will be appericated

Comment: Which API levels are you targeting? What's the API level of the device you're testing on?

Comment: The API level on the device is 28